# How to convert array into strings?

Tags: ruby

I have an output as such:

```
require_relative "array_sort"

arraystudents = []

puts "Type a student name:"
name = gets.chomp
arraystudents.push(name)

while name != ""
    puts "Type another student name or press enter to finish:"
    name = gets.chomp
    arraystudents.push(name)
end

puts "Congratulations! Your Array has #{arraystudents.count} students: #{array_sort(arraystudents)}"
```

Every time I run it, I end up with an array output rather than just having the names under string form.

Is there a way where the output can be along the lines of: x, y and z? Rather than array, or just commas separating each name?

On another note, I seem to also have a blank [0] at the beginning of my array.

Here's on the `array_sort.rb` file.

```
def array_sort(students)
  return students.sort.join(",")
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting an element of the array also on the last iteration

i suggest doing something like this to avoid the last element of the array

```
arraystudents = []

puts "Type a student name:"
name = gets.chomp
arraystudents.push(name)
loop do
    puts "Type another student name or press enter to finish:"
    name = gets.chomp
    break if name == ""
    arraystudents.push(name)
end
puts "Congratulations! Your Array has #{arraystudents.count} students: #{arraystudents.sort.join(',')}"
```

The codes outputs

```
Type a student name:
1
Type another student name or press enter to finish:
2
Type another student name or press enter to finish:
3
Type another student name or press enter to finish:

Congratulations! Your Array has 3 students: 1,2,3
```

If you want to have the "and" you can do

```
arraystudents = []

puts "Type a student name:"
name = gets.chomp
arraystudents.push(name)
# puts arraystudents.join(',')
loop do
    puts "Type another student name or press enter to finish:"
    name = gets.chomp
    break if name == ""
    arraystudents.push(name)
    # puts arraystudents.join(',')
end
arraystudents = arraystudents.sort 
if (arraystudents.count == 1)
    puts "Congratulations! Your Array has 1 students: #{arraystudents[0]}"
else 
    puts "Congratulations! Your Array has #{arraystudents.count} students: #{arraystudents[0..-2].join(',')} and #{arraystudents[-1]}"
end
```

and the output will be

```
Type a student name:
3
Type another student name or press enter to finish:
2
Type another student name or press enter to finish:
1
Type another student name or press enter to finish:

Congratulations! Your Array has 3 students: 1,2 and 3
```

Comment: Edited the answer. You can do the same thing to check if is less then 1

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an extra blank entry at the end of `arraystudents`. `arraystudents.sort` makes it look at it's at the front.

The problem is because you check if name is empty, *then* you ask for a name and push it into `arraystudents`. Ask, push, then check. Instead you need to ask, check, then push.

```
arraystudents = []

loop do
  puts "Type another student name or press enter to finish:"
  name = gets.chomp

  break if name == ''
  
  arraystudents.push(name)
end
```

[`loop`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) is an infinite loop. [`break`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-break+Statement) lets you exit a loop.

---

> Is there a way where the output can be along the lines of: x, y and z?

Yes. First handle the case when you have 0 or 1 students. This avoids results like  `and Zara`.

When there's multiple students: Sort them. Remove the last student. Join the rest. Then concatenate them.

```
def display_students(students)
  case students.size
  when 0, 1
    return students.first
  else
    sorted_students = students.sort
    last = sorted_students.pop
    
    return "#{sorted_students.join(', ')} and #{last}"
  end
end
```

There may be more elegant ways, but it gets the job done.